# Using Visual Studio Online (VSO) for SQL Server Source Control

Tags: version-control, sql-server-2012, azure-devops

I have been looking for solutions to providing source control for my SQL Server 2012 instance. I have looked at Red-Gate's solution but it is outside my price range. Since I already make use of Visual Studio Online (VSO) source control for my .NET projects I was wondering if it was able to provide source control for SQL Server?

I have seen articles (listed below) that discuss using Team Foundation Server (TFS) for source control however I do not have a dedicated TFS server, just VSO.

- [Use Team Foundation Server (TFS) as your Source Control in SSMS](http://www.techtree.co.uk/sql-server/management-studio-ssms/use-team-foundation-server-tfs-as-your-source-control-in-ssms/)
- [Using the TFS as a source control repository for SSMS projects](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1962/using-the-tfs-as-a-source-control-repository-for-ssms-projects)

  Has anyone made use of VSO to handle source control for their SQL Server database?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem for using VSO for your situation

Comment: How would you use VSO to manage version control?

Comment: Checkout the second comment on the first article you posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using Visual Studio Online or Team Foundation Server to hold your database scheme in version control.  There is a fairly recent article in Visual Studio Magazine that discusses using the [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) to be able to make that easier for you:  [Simplifying Development with Visual Studio Database Projects](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/12/01/visual-studio-database-projects.aspx).  SSDT is available for any version of Visual Studio including the Community and Express editions.

[image: SQL Server Data Tools]

Answer (score 1):

Redgate was out of my price range too unfortunately...

The SSDT tools for VS are amazing, and i recently started using it for comparing DB versions - and then generating change scripts.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)'s a start point if you want to get into that...

**Other Free Alternatives?**

1. [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)
2. [gitSQL](http://www.gitsql.net)

**Liquibase** - i couldn't get my head around but if you can get it working, it may be better for other databases, if you have the requirement to use other databases.

I use **gitSQL** - it's free up to 20 tables...
If you have more than 20 tables then it costs $40 - which is still so much cheaper than the redgate solution.

gitSQL are also setting up command line options in a future release, so potentially you could run it via a batch file, and set up continuous integration.

gitSQL are also talking about postgres, mysql editions in the future.